# What is the type signature of a range from the range-v3 library in C

Tags: c++, range-v3

Given the code below:

```
// This example demonstrates filtering and transforming a range on the
// fly with view adaptors.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <range/v3/view/filter.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>
using std::cout;
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> const vi{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    using namespace ranges;
    auto rng = vi | views::filter([](int i) { return i % 2 == 0; }) |
               views::transform([](int i) { return std::to_string(i); });
    // prints: [2,4,6,8,10]
    cout << rng << '\n';
}
```

How do encapsulate the logic above into a specific function that returns a range I can pipe? I'm thinking a function that can take a range and output a range. I will need the type signature of a range and I'm not sure how to find out that type signature or write it out? Is there documentation on specifically how to do this and how do I find this out?

Comment: `auto my_func(parameters) { code; ...; return filtered_range; }`?

Comment: But I need to declare the function first in an .h file to prevent circular dependencies so I need the type signature.

Comment: Can you not also define the function in the header file?

Comment: Would `decltype()` help you here?

Comment: @NathanOliver I would like to declare it in the header file and define it in the cc file.

Comment: @Galik but then I would be redefining the entire function in the type signature.